# how to see the request in laravel 6

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, http, laravel-5

Hey I am new to laravel.
I have this html code
[image]

and this is what I have in the method.
[image]

Is their a way to see the request? in the view? in the developer tools?
I just want to see the request.

Comment: You can dump the `request` in `controller`, something like this `dd($request)`

Comment: tnx it worked well

Comment: You could use [debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) or [clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) to see it in your devtools

Answer (score 0):

You can dump the `request` in `controller`, or `return` the `request` as `json`

```
public function someFun($request)
{
   // dump $request
   dd($request);

   // return as json
   return response()->json($request);
}
```